# How to prevent the "Hide" action button from resetting all user inputs in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

The below code works fine, except that when the user clicks the "Hide" button followed by the "Show" button, any user inputs into the 2nd matrix are lost. I would like all user inputs to be retained, and only reset to 0 when the App is closed. I may add a "Reset" button later to give the user the option to clear inputs.

Here is how the App is supposed to work. At inception, user is presented with a slider input for number of periods to model (`periods`) and a first matrix input grid for values (`base_input`) to plot over time. Note that only the 1st row of this matrix input grid, row A, is functional for the sake of simpler example code.

Right beneath the above inputs in the side panel, user has the option to "Show" and "Hide" a 2nd matrix input grid (`vector_input`, in the `output$Vectors <- renderUI({` section of `Server`) to run a more complex plot of 2 time variables (first time variable from slider input (`periods`) and 2nd time variable in left column of this 2nd matrix input grid) and the variable to plot over time (right column of this 2nd matrix input grid). Note that the 1st and 2nd matrices have linked initial values. This works fine.

But the user may want to input into the 2nd matrix, then subsequently hide it (for example to see other items that appear below it in the full App code), and then subsequently show that same 2nd matrix input again to tweak further by hitting the "Show" button. Unfortunately, as coded below, that 2nd matrix input clears out when "Show" is clicked after having been hidden. Not good. A better solution will be a Reset button (with a pop message asking the user if they are sure, because in real-life usage the construction of these vectors takes a lot of manipulation and changes by the user before they are finalized). Note that there is a minor bug in the shinyMatrix 2nd matrix input grid (to enter additional values in this extendable matrix, you have to click and input into the right column before before entering a corresponding value into the left column - I have the fix for this but haven't yet implemented it).

Code (the defined functions at the top can be safely ignored, the core ui/server sections are very stripped down):

```
library(shiny);library(shinyMatrix);library(shinyjs)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}  

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- y  
  a[,1][a[,1]>x] <- x 
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE])
  b[b<=0] <- NA              
  b <- c(1,b)                
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a)
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  return(a)}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vector.multi <- function(x,y,z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, x)
  a[y] <- z
  a[seq_len(min(y)-1)] <- a[min(y)]
  if(max(y) < x){a[seq(max(y)+1, x, 1)] <- 0}
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, z = a)
  return(c)}

vector.multiFinal <- function(x,y){vector.multi(x,matrix.validate(x,y)[,1],matrix.validate(x,y)[,2])}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==2",
                       sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
                       matrix1.input("base_input"),
                       useShinyjs(),
                       actionButton('showBtn','Show vector'), 
                       actionButton('hideBtn','Hide vector'),
                       uiOutput("Vectors")),
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,plotOutput("graph1")),
        id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  periods       <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input    <- reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input  <- reactive(input$vector_input)

  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input", 
                      value=matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2, 
                                   dimnames=list(NULL, c("Y","Z")))
    ) # close update matrix
  }) # close observe event
  
  # --- Show performance vector if user elects
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    req(input$showBtn)
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]))
  }) # close render UI
  
  observeEvent(input$showBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(
    if(input$showBtn == 0)
      plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1]),type="b")
    else
      plot(vector.multiFinal(periods(),matrix.validate(periods(),vector_input())),type="b")
    ) # close render plot
 }) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your above code the expression `req(input$showBtn)` in `renderUI` is resetting `output$Vectors`. I deleted it and added a call to `hidden` in the UI to hide `Vectors` on startup. (I also added a reset button)

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny);library(shinyMatrix);library(shinyjs)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}  

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- y  
  a[,1][a[,1]>x] <- x 
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE])
  b[b<=0] <- NA              
  b <- c(1,b)                
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a)
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  return(a)}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vector.multi <- function(x,y,z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, x)
  a[y] <- z
  a[seq_len(min(y)-1)] <- a[min(y)]
  if(max(y) < x){a[seq(max(y)+1, x, 1)] <- 0}
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, z = a)
  return(c)}

vector.multiFinal <- function(x,y){vector.multi(x,matrix.validate(x,y)[,1],matrix.validate(x,y)[,2])}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==2",
                       sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
                       matrix1.input("base_input"),
                       useShinyjs(),
                       actionButton('showBtn','Show vector'), 
                       actionButton('hideBtn','Hide vector'),
                       actionButton('resetBtn','Reset vector'),
                       hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))),
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,plotOutput("graph1")),
      id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  periods       <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input    <- reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input  <- reactive(input$vector_input)
  
  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input", 
                      value=matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2, 
                                   dimnames=list(NULL, c("Y","Z")))
    ) # close update matrix
  }) # close observe event
  
  # --- Show performance vector if user elects
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetBtn
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]))
  }) # close render UI
  
  observeEvent(input$showBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(
    if(input$showBtn == 0)
      plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1]),type="b")
    else
      plot(vector.multiFinal(periods(),matrix.validate(periods(),vector_input())),type="b")
  ) # close render plot
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you ismirsehregal, works beautifully! I didn-t know about the "hidden" function, very useful.